# NInject. Register generic types

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, entity

Please explain how to bind a generic type to its implementer if that implementer is also a generic class, for example,  `IRepository<T>` and `EfRepository<T>`. I need just one action to register this binding

Comment: Please try to rephrase your request as a question and provide more information.

Comment: I need to know how to register a generic type into any Inversion Container .. I have no issues to register non-generic types, but the problem here is generics. For example, I have a generic interface IDataService<TEntity> and then I have one of implementers like WcfDataService<TEntity> where TEntity: BaseEntity ... I need to know how in the code I should register the pattern: --- register an interface with all of its possible generic types to his generic implementer

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use the overload that accepts a type parameter and leave the generic argument out.

```
kernel.Bind(typeof(IRepository<>)).To(typeof(EfRepository<>));
```